# What are appdomains?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

In plain simple english , what's an **appdomain** ? And where It could be useful to use it ? what's the problems solved by it . (please don't mark this as duplicate) , I need a simple answer .

Comment: Also consider taking a look at the following MSDN article: [Application Domains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I did some googling before posting this question , but still don't get it .

Comment: Then it would help if you articulated what exactly you "do not get".